# Assets Directory Usability When Editing An Image

Tags: assets

[image: Editing an Image, but full path to image is incorrect]I would like the CRAFT CMS to return to the current directory after I edit an image.

Let's say I'm viewing a list of images in "assets > images > misc"

I edit an image from that directory and then "save".

The assets tool does not return to "assets > images > misc" - instead, it returns to "assets > images".

This forces the user to re-navigate to "assets > images > misc" to edit another image.

Further, when editing an image out of that directory, the current directory shown at the top of the page is incorrect. It shows "assets > images" when I'm technically editing an image out of "assets > images > misc" (picture attached).

Can this be fixed to save the user countless unnecessary clicks?

Comment: This sounds like more of a feature request?  If so the best place for it to live is here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me... sorry, being honest.

Comment: No need to apologize. Bug or FR, they both go here. :) https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues